# Delete file icon using command line

Tags: bash, macos

I know how to delete the file/folder icon using GetInfo. Also know how to change it in terminal using Sips/Rez and Derez. How would I ONLY delete file/folder icon in terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command `SetFile -a c <path>`.